# How to interrupt an infinite loop?

Tags: python, mouseevent

I have a program which prints a message whenever the left mouse button is triggered, and a different program which prints out the live coordinates of the active window. I need to combine these programs so that after the mouse down event has been triggered, the window coordinate program loops until the mouse up event is triggered.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it though.

```
#check if left or right mouse buttons were pressed
import pyautogui, sys
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow, GetWindowRect
from pynput import mouse2

mouse_trigger = "up"
#detect left click up and down and prints coordinates on each event
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global mouse_trigger
    if button == mouse2.Button.left:
        x = pyautogui.position()[0]
        y = pyautogui.position()[1]
        if mouse_trigger == "down":
            mouse_trigger = "up"
            print(x, y)
        elif mouse_trigger == "up":
            mouse_trigger = "down"
            print(x, y)
        print(mouse_trigger)

# Collect events until released
with mouse2.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()

##get live window coords
while test == 1:
    print(GetWindowRect(GetForegroundWindow()))
```

Comment: https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/

Comment: Use something like threads or async.